# QuickOSM times out when running a query

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I am using Qgis 3.22.16, and QuickOSM ver 2.2.0.

I have tried to run a query from an observed area in OSM at 1:100000 scale. It is a small town in SE QLD, Australia. When I open QuickOSM, I select highway under the Key dropdown. Leave value empty. Click from Canvas Extent, click run and it comes up with an error at the top of the screen: `Over Pass API Download Failed, Connection Timed out`. I had done the exact same process a few weeks ago using QGIS 3.22.7 and had no problems.

I have selected remote areas and larger populated areas; it makes no difference, regardless of the size of the town or area.

Comment: What is your set time out time?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to your timeout set in QuickOSM :

[image: QuickOSM timeout]

And also in QGIS settings :

[image: QGIS timeout]

What is the server your are using in the background ? In QuickOSM settings ?

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to the latest version 2.2.1 of QuickOSM, the list of Overpass server has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating to QGIS 3.22.16. Changing the Server in QuickOSM-Settings, as mentioned by [etrimaille](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/456242/221977), from `lz4.overpass-api.de` to `z.overpass-api.de` did the trick. The queries running now without problems.

The actual timeout setting in QuickOSM was not helping, the query timed out even before the set timeout.

Comment: Please use overpass-api.de instead of a single hostname like z.overpass-api.de (which may go away in the near future as well!)

Comment: Yes, did this and updated to QuickOSM 2.2.1. Everything working that way! Thanks!